# change innertext of clone element

Tags: javascript

Clone element entire tree removed as soon we make change with `innerText`

```
clnElem.id = "name" + [i]; ==> i is getting value from counter
newChildElem = parentBlock.appendChild(clnElem); ==> parentBlock is parent div reference created
clnElem.innerText = "some text";
```

Already tried to add text before append.

Comment: Assigning to `innerText` replaces everything in the node with that text.

Comment: If you don't want to replace the entire tree, find a more specific element and replace its text.

Comment: If you want better help, you need to show your HTML, and what the resulting HTML should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clnElem doesn't have any inner text, but it contains the node that has the text. When you set clnElem's inner text, it gets transofrmed into a text-node, which cannot have children. So you have to locate the real text-node that's somewhere in clnElem's tree, for example

```
clnElem.firstChild.lastChild.innerText = "some text";
```

I would have to see the HTML tree for the exact right code

Comment: Thanks for the help.....clone node had text at beginning but without any "tag", so i assigned a tag and replacing the innerText, with
clnElem.firstChild.lastChild.innerText = "some text";